# ggplot how to get legend line colours match those on the main plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm creating a simple point and line plot in ggplot similar to the example below:

```
dat <- iris %>%                               # dummy data
       select(Sepal.Length) %>% 
       mutate(Type = "Sepal.Length")

ggplot() +
geom_point(data = dat, aes(x = as.numeric(row.names(dat)), y = Sepal.Length, shape = Type), colour = "orange") +
scale_shape_manual(values =  10) +
geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 6, linetype = 'C Red line'), colour = "red", size = 0.5) +
geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 5, linetype = 'A Blue line'), colour = "darkblue", size = 0.5) +
geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 7, linetype = 'B Green line'), colour = "forestgreen", size = 0.5) +
scale_linetype_manual(values = c('solid', 'dashed', 'dotted')) +
labs(linetype = "Line legend") +
labs(shape = "Point legend")
```

[image: Example plot]

I'ev worked out that the alphabetical order of the 'names' associated with each line controls the order in the legend and I can match a desired line style to those lines using scale_linetype_manual.  However,  I cannot work out how to get the colours of the lines on the plot to be matched by the colours in linetype legend, which just uses the last specifed line colour?

Comment: This is exactly why I prefer the crystal clear logic of low level plotting, try `clr <- c('orange', 'red', 'darkblue', 'forestgreen'); plot(dat$Sepal.Length, pch=20, col=clr[1]); abline(h=c(6, 5, 7), lty=c(3, 1, 2), col=clr[-1]); legend('topleft', legend=c('Sepal.Length', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Red'), pch=c(20, rep(NA, 3)), col=clr, lty=c(NA, c(3, 1, 2)))`, servus!

Comment: I agreed that the base R is much more intuitive but I'm trying to learn how to do things in GGPLOT to increase my skill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I would do.

1. Instead of 3 individual `geom_hline` calls, let `ggplot2` automatically plot horizontal lines based on data from a `vert_data` `data.frame`.
2. Combine legends for `linetype` and `colour`.

```r
vert_data <- data.frame(
    yintercept = c(6, 5, 7),
    name = c("C Red line", "A Blue line", "B Green line"),
    linetype = c("dotted", "solid", "dashed"),
    colour = c("red", "darkblue", "forestgreen"))

ggplot() +
    geom_point(
        data = dat, 
        aes(x = as.numeric(row.names(dat)), y = Sepal.Length, shape = Type), 
        colour = "orange") +
    scale_shape_manual(values =  10) +
    geom_hline(
        data = vert_data,
        aes(yintercept = yintercept, linetype = name, colour = name),
        size = 0.5) +
    scale_linetype_manual(
        "Line legend", values = setNames(vert_data$linetype, vert_data$name)) +
    scale_colour_manual(
        "Line legend", values = setNames(vert_data$colour, vert_data$name)) +
    labs(shape = "Point legend")
```

[image]

Comment: I like your solution to the problem but I would still be interested if it is possible to get GGPLOT a solution to the case of adding a line at a time